# Stuck on this variable exponent problem

Tags: exponential-function

$$908.80 = 250(1+\frac{0.24}{m})^{6m}$$

I get stuck here because one of the m's is part of the ln:

$$ln908.8 = m(6ln250 + 6ln250\frac{0.24}{m})$$

Not sure how to pull it out. I've tried various things but keep getting the wrong answer; I know the final answer is supposed to be m=0.99. Any help?

Comment: Recall, $ln(\frac{a}{b})=ln(a)-ln(b)$

Comment: You're not going to be able to find a final answer to this algebraically.

Comment: Your second line doesn't follow from your first line.  Did you try to distribute log over a sum?

Comment: $$6mln250(1+\frac{0.24}{m})$$, then I distributed it, then factored out the m

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [Lambert-$W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) for this. There is no solution in terms of elementary functions.

EDIT: Rewrite the equation as

$${\left(\sqrt[6]{\frac{908.80}{250}}\right)}^{1/m}=1+0.24\frac1m$$

Letting $1/m=x$, we have

$${\left(\sqrt[6]{\frac{908.80}{250}}\right)}^{x}=1+0.24x$$

which is of the form $p^x=ax+b$ and whose solution is in general given by

$$x=\frac{-W\left(-\frac{\ln p}{a}\,p^{-b/a}\right)}{\ln p}-\frac{b}a$$

and making the approipriate substitutions yields $m$ in terms of the Lambert-$W$ function.

Comment: I am not sure that Lambert function could be used for this problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have clarified how to use it for this problem; see the edit.

Comment: I apologize for my stupidity !

Comment: That wasn't stupid, it was just wrong. No need to apologize; we're all wrong at times. We all make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Without the W function you are in for a numeric solution.  I like fixed point iteration, so would take logs
$$908.80 = 250(1+\frac{0.24}{m})^{6m}\\\log 908.80=\log 250+6m\log(1+\frac {0.24}m)\\m=\frac{\log 908.80-\log 250}{6 \log(1+\frac{0.24}m)}$$ and iterate
$$m_{i+1}=\frac{\log 908.80-\log 250}{6 \log(1+\frac{0.24}{m_i})}$$ to convergence at about $m=0.999968$

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Ross Millikan answered, a numerical method is required. So, considering that me need to find the zero of equation
$$f(m)=\log (250)+6m\log\left(1+\frac {0.24}m\right)-\log( 908.80)$$ that is to say $$f(m)=m\log\left(1+\frac {0.24}m\right)-\frac16 \log\left(\frac {908.8}{250}\right)$$ let me be very lazy and start Newton iterations using $m_0=0.5$. The successive iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & m_n \\
 0 & 0.50000000 \\
 1 & 0.78190010 \\
 2 & 0.95860749 \\
 3 & 0.99848163 \\
 4 & 0.99996602 \\
 5 & 0.99996794
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**